# Replicate a Facebook page and all its content

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I would like to achieve the following:

1. `GET` all posts from a page and their related content (attachments, likes, visibility, tags, shares, comments, creation time...)
2. `POST` all that content in a new page

Assuming that I am admin of both pages.

I know that it's pretty straight forward to loop over the feed of a page and get all the posts' information. However, I'm not so sure about the `POST` part:

- I guess that Facebook doesn't allow to "clone" people's
  like/shares/comments below each post, on their behalf?
- Considering that I will delete the first page, will all attachments disappear from Facebook's servers as well?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post in behalf of another user. And you cannot get all information you need with the Graph API.

What about renaming the page? If you like to delete the first page and clone it before, it looks like a rebranding or something ...

Comment: True, but the configuration here is kind of weird: our client would like to create a new `global` page and sub-pages (localization), then replicate all the existing content from the original page to the new ones. I don't know if that makes sense. I played around with the graph API and it seems that I can get pretty much all info, could you tell what data won't be available, according to you?

Comment: The users that liked the page. page/likes returns a different value ...